# How to deploy socket io & express server on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy socket io + express server on heroku for a chat application but i am facing a trouble while deploying the server .

First this is my server code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server running...');

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
connections.push(socket);
console.log('Connected %s sockets connected ', connections.length);


//Disconnect 
socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username),1);
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
  console.log('Disconneted : %s sockets connected',connections.length);
  
});

});
```

This is my package.json file

```
  {
 "name": "",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "chat application",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node index"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "socket.io": "*",
 "express": "*"
 }
 }
```

But I'm getting this error

> ### Cannot GET /

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (socket.io with express and react).

You can add to server this line:

```
app.use(express.static('some path to a static file'));
```

e.g. 
`app.use(express.static('client/build'))`

works for me assuming in package.json has this line at "scripts":

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing wrong deployed application. Your app still waits for connection on port 3000 (or port from process.env.PORT). App responds "Cannot GET /" because you don't have any routes.

To see how routes can be implemented look at this -> https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

To see how connect using socket.io (client part) look at this -> https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO